# Most efficient way to display PNG map tiles?

Tags: php, leaflet, png, openstreetmap, tiles

I used TileMill to create a map for the few states I needed, exported as .mbtiles and then used mbutil to convert them to PNG files. I proceeded to upload my tiles to my server through Filezilla just to see how long it took for the tiles to render.

Is the method i'm using of uploading tiles to my GoDaddy server and rendering them frowned upon? I assume there are a few cons of doing it this way, but couldn't really find said info. Should I use a certain type of software to render said tiles instead, say TileServer? My three main priorities are

1. Rendering Speed (Fastest, most efficient way to display tiles)
2. Cost (Strictly open source, boss hates spending money)
3. Language (Preferably PHP as I'm not fluent in Python)

[My Delaware Map](https://www.everyhome.com/maps/leaflet.htm)

```
<html>
<head> 
 <title>A Leaflet map!</title> 
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="./leaflet.css"/> 
 <script src="./leaflet.js"></script> 
 <style> #map{ height: 100% } </style>
</head>
<body> 
 <div id="map"></div> 

 <script> // initialize the map
  var map = L.map('map').setView([38.91, -75.52], 10);
   map.options.minZoom = 9;
   map.options.maxZoom = 16;
  L.tileLayer('https://www.everyhome.com/maps/delaware/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
   maxZoom: 16,
  }).addTo(map); 
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**My Evil Plan with this data:** I could have anywhere from 100-200 people looking at the same map at a single time and my main priority is the speed of the tiles rendering for clients. I plan to add a data layer on top of my tiles that show zip code/school district outlines, with another data layer that is made up of house points.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I'm not terribly familiar with the specific pieces you're using, but you should try to minimize the amount of work you do more than once, eg: put a cache between the client and the renderer so that your tiles are rendered once at most. You could also offload the actual rendering to something scalable and usage-based like AppEngine so as not to overload the machine actually serving your website.

Comment: Tile rendering is a very broad topic, please familiarize yourself with switch2osm.org and try to ask more specific questions. Just to put that into perspective: there are about 300 questions covering the rendering topic on help.openstreetmap.org/tags/rendering alone...  Also, what exactly is your question?